# Hard drive overheating on an Asus K53SV

Tags: 12.04, power-management

Hello I am new to Linux and using Edubuntu 12.04 lts 64 bit from past 7 days, on my laptop( asus k53sv. core i7,8gb ram,750 gb , nvidia gt 540 m.) I have managed to solve nvidia's optimus driver problem (over heating in Ubuntu) using bumblebee and its quiet stable now with 49-55 deg c processor temp, The only problem is with my hard disk it seems like overheating while i am using Ubuntu, with windows 7 its running cool @34-36 deg c, but when ever i am switching to Ubuntu its like 40-44 deg c. I read in some pages that Ubuntu may harm laptop hard drive and battery status. the problem is about "Load Cycle Count" is that so??

1. http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/1038568/ubuntu-eats-laptop-hard-drive
2. http://www.dvhardware.net/article22922.html

please please please tell me if there's any way to solve this hdd overheating problem ? or i should avoid Ubuntu for my laptop ???

p.s i am using Edubuntu 12.04 64 bit lts.

- Release 12.04 (precise) 64-bit.
- Kernel Linux 3.2.0-24-generic.
- GNOME 3.4.1

Comment: well it depend on hard-drive usage ... my temp of HD is 47 -50 ( intensive usage ) normally it is 43 to 45

Comment: oh so its safe and normal right?

Comment: yes it is safe..........& don't delete the question may be some one   answer with detail...i hope you understand

Answer (score 2):

Here I found a post .It says the problem will be resolved with the new release of the kernel.
http://techhamlet.com/2012/05/ubuntu-12-04-runs-on-new-laptops-without-over-heating/

Comment: Thanks for the help friends,as far as i think use Ubuntu 12.04 is not leading to harm/damage any of my Laptop Hardware , am I right?

Comment: That link refers to overheating of the CPU, not of the hard drive.